# Compare two files and ignore the matching content and append the unmatched content from file 2 to file 1 in a specific format

Tags: text-processing

I have 2 files need to compare file1 2ns and 3 ed columns with file2 first and the second column if matches leave it if not match append the data in file1 by adding 2019 as the first column and 0 as the last column.
is this possible?

File1

```
2019  ABCD 1 10
2019  DEF  2 11
2019  GHI  1 20
2019  jkl  2 25
```

File2

```
ABCD 1
jkl  1
mnop  2
qrst  1
```

expected Result

```
2019  ABCD 1 10
2019  DEF  2 11
2019  GHI  1 20
2019  jkl  2 25
2019  jkl  1  0
2019  mnop  2  0
2019  qrst  1  0
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
awk '
     FNR==NR {seen[$2,$3]=1; print $0 }
     FNR!=NR && !seen[$1,$2] { print 2019,$0,0 }
' file1 file2
```

Explanation:

- `FNR==NR { ... }` Run the commands in brackets only for first file.
- `seen[$2,$3]=1`, set array `seen` with key $2,$3 to 1.
- `print $0` print the full row.
- `FNR!=NR && !seen[$1,$2] { ... }` Run the commands in brackets only if not first file and if fields $1,$2 are not keys in `seen` array.
- `print 2019,$0,0` print the row surrounded by new columns 2019 and 0.

Add `| column -t` for aligned output.

Output:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{seen[$2,$3]++; print $0} FNR!=NR && !seen[$1,$2]{print 2019,$0,0}' file1 file2 | column -t
2019  ABCD  1  10
2019  DEF   2  11
2019  GHI   1  20
2019  jkl   2  25
2019  jkl   1  0
2019  mnop  2  0
2019  qrst  1  0
```

Comment: what you mean by full date? Where should it come from? And for creating new file from a command you can simply redirect the output to a file, add `> file3` at the end of the command

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2$3]++; print; next}!($1$2 in a){print "2019",$0,"0"}' file1 file2 
2019  ABCD 1 10
2019  DEF  2 11
2019  GHI  1 20
2019  jkl  2 25
2019 jkl  1 0
2019 mnop  2 0
2019 qrst  1 0
```

#### Explanation

- `NR==FNR` : NR is the current line number, FNR is the line number of the current file. The two will be identical only while the 1st file is being read.
- `{a[$2$3]++; print; next}` : while reading the first file (`file1`), use the 2nd and 3rd fields as a key for th associative array `a`. This is just used to keep track of which ones we have already seen. Then, print this line and move on to the next. This `next` ensures the rest of the script will only be run for the second file, when `NR` is not the same as `FNR`.
- `!($1$2 in a)` : if the first and second fields of this line are not used as keys in the `a` array (this means the 1st and 2nd fields concatenated, so if the 1st is `foo` ad the second `bar`, `$1$2` will be `foobar`).
- `{print "2019",$0,"0"}`: print `2019`, the current line from `file2` and `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very different way to do it:

```
mkns() {
    # make keys from parameters $2 and $3 for joining, then sort the keys
    sort -k 1b,1 <(awk "{print \$$2\$$3, \$0}" $1)
}
```

Then run

```
join -j 1 -v 2 <(mkns file1 2 3) <(mkns file2 1 2) | awk '{print 2019, $2, $3, 0}' | cat file1 - | column -t
```

This is not as short as the purely `awk` solutions by RoVo and tendon, but I think this is an interesting solution because `join` can be used to "filter out" rows that you want.